# outlook : Message not sent in Rich text format

Tags: outlook

I am using Outlook version 14.0.7165.5000 (32 bit)

Under Options -> Mail -> Compose Messages , I have 'compose message in this format' as Rich Text.

While sending mail, I even select Rich Text under Format text tab.

But, even then the attachment are not within the mail body? 
The mail is getting sent as HTML format.

Comment: Consider some clients/webmail will convert RTF to HTML for display.  HTML is a better format choice anyway.

Comment: My manager wants me to send in RTF only. It is his  'choice'.

Comment: How to stop some clients/webmail converting RTF to HTML for display?